# Bootstrap 5 Modal Percentage Width

Tags: css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

How can I make the bootstrap 5 modal a percentage of width of full screen?  This used to work in Boostrap previous versions below..

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered per80" role="document" >


.per80 {
    width: 80% !important;
}
```

OR

```
$(".modal-dialog").css("width", "80%");`
```

I have tried to add a class or style="width: 80%" but none of this seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't fit the modal to 80% or more is that you have a maximum width property on the Bootstrap modal.

Also be careful, the percentage is not based on the width of the window, but on the width of its parent. To get a value related to your window, you should use the `vw` unit.

You can try this :

```
width: 80vw;
max-width: initial;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  I had to remove the max-width property of @media.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .modal-dialog {
        /*max-width: 500px;*/
        margin: 1.75rem auto;
    }
```